# storing username in ruby using session and database serious problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have been tearing my hair out for the last 24 hours, all I am really trying to do is simple. A user has an edit page where they can edit thier details, but before I can do this I need to retrieve the student unique identifier (k_number) is my database primary key in the student database.

```
def edit
    @title = "Edit Your Details"

    @user_id = session["user_id"]  
    @current_user = Student.find_by_k_number(session["user_id"])
end
```

Its just not working, when I look at the backend query, the k_number is being passed as null. Please help

Comment: Where are you storing the user id into the session variable?

Comment: There is not a lot to go on here...and I'd like to help. Can you put the incoming parameters and perhaps dump the session? That might be enough to suggest a few places to look closer at what you've got...

Comment: Are you sure that `session["user_id"]` really returns what you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
 @current_user = Student.find_by_k_number(params[:user_id])
```